# Flutter: Provider and how to update records from the DB in the background

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am new to Flutter and I have this simple use case: in my Cloud Firestore DB I have a list of JSON representing events. I want to show them through my Flutter app in a ListView.

My requirements is that the `ListView` doesn't refresh in real-time but only when a pull-on refresh (implemented using `RefreshIndicator`) is done by the user or when the app resumes from background

I tried to implement this in 2 ways (I am using `provider` package for state management):

1. Using `StreamProvider` to create a stream of records from the DB. This continuosly updates the list view (basically the widget changes while the user is looking at it and I don't want this)
2. Using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` that refers to a `EventManager` class which holds a `List<Event>`. This class has a `pull` method which updates its internal state. I call this method when the user does the pull-on refresh (in the `onRefresh` callback of `RefreshIndicator`).

Option 2 seems to work well however I do not know how to implement the refresh when the app resumes from background. As I said I am using `provider` (and therefore `StatelessWidget`) and apparently there is no way to bind to these events when using `StatelessWidget`s

Do you have any suggestions and best practices for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access Flutters lifecycle methods and fire a callback when the app resumes.

You can add a stateful widget with `WidgetsBindingObserver` and put that somewhere in the scope of your `Provider`, but as a parent of whatever widget you use to display the info.

Or you can make your `PullToRefresh` widget stateful and do the same thing.

```
class LifeCycleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LifeCycleWidgetState createState() => _LifeCycleWidgetState();
}

class _LifeCycleWidgetState extends State<LifeCycleWidget>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState _appLifecycleState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    refreshOnResume();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      _appLifecycleState = state;
    });
    refreshOnResume();
  }

  void refreshOnResume() {
    if (_appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      print('resumed');
      // your refresh method here
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomePage();
  }
}
```

Add the following to your main method if it's not there already.

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Another way to do it without adding a stateful widget would be with [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get). You can still keep all your Provider stuff but only use the `SuperController` which provides lifecycle methods. This I can't test because I don't have your Provider code but you can probably get away with creating the class below and initializing the controller somewhere within the scope of the relevant `Provider` widget with
`Get.put(LifeCycleController());`

Then call the function in the `onResumed` override and you can use `Get.context` if you need context.

```
class LifeCycleController extends SuperController {
  @override
  void onDetached() {
    debugPrint('on detached');
  }

  @override
  void onInactive() {
    debugPrint('on inactive');
  }

  @override
  void onPaused() {
    debugPrint('on pause');
  }

  @override
  void onResumed() {
// your refresh function here. Access context with Get.context
    debugPrint('on resume');
  }
}
```